# querywrapper of mybatisPlus

Tags: mybatis-plus

`LambdaQueryWrapper<Follow>lambdaQueryWrapper=new LambdaQueryWrapper<>(); lambdaQueryWrapper.eq(Follow::getUserId,userId).eq(Follow::getFollowUserId,id); remove(lambdaQueryWrapper);`

`QueryWrapper<Follow> queryWrapper = new QueryWrapper<>(); queryWrapper.eq("user_id", userId) .eq("follow_user_id", id); remove(queryWrapper);`

what are the difference between the code above? why the first error like:org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error evaluating expression 'ew.sqlSegment != null and ew.sqlSegment != '' and ew.nonEmptyOfWhere'. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.ognl.OgnlException: sqlSegment [java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError]

help please！ I can not deal with it